# How to discover and delete unused accounts?

Tags: users, customization, account

I'm running a Wordpress self hosted blog with registration and I would like to know if there is a safe way to know if users hasn't login yet or if account is unused by a long time.
What I would like to achieve is to be able to automatically delete accounts that aren't unused by 6 months or more or not used at all.
Any help?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's several plugins in the directory that will track the last login time of your users, each with various options:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=last+login

You could use one of those to track login times, and then delete unused accounts based on the information one of those plugins provides.